# How to link this button to another page

Tags: css, xcode, html

https://jsbin.com/jaboyeleta/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="sub-main">
<button class="button-two"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
</div>
```

Im pretty newsih at this, and i need help knowing where to place the 
snippet of code to link this button to my site, any help? Sorry if this is a silly question to ask here. I tried to find videos.

Comment: Replace your button tag with this: `<button class="button-two" onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com/");'><span>Hover Me</span></button>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <div class="sub-main">
      <a href="https://google.com">
         <button class="button-two"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
      </a>
  </div>
```

Maybe you can read more about links and another HTML stuff [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_links.asp)

Comment: lol great minds think alike saw your answer right after I hit post

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button in an **a** tag like so:

```
<div class="sub-main">
   <a href='https://www.google.com'>
      <button class="button-two"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
   </a>
 </div>
```